# How to use onBackPressed in BottonNavigationView?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

How can I use onBackPressed in BottonNavigationView to select an item? For example, if I press item 2 I go to fragment number 2, but when I push back, I go back to fragment number 1 and item 2 is still selected, item 1 is not selected which is the one corresponding to fragment 1 ...

This is my code

```
private BottomNavigationViewEx.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
    = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();


    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.mapa:
            transaction.replace(R.id.content, new MapFragment());
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            transaction.commit();

            return true;

        case R.id.taxi:
            transaction.replace(R.id.content, new TaxiFragment());
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            transaction.commit();

            return true;

        case R.id.help:
            transaction.replace(R.id.content, new HelpFragment());
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            transaction.commit();

            return true;

        case R.id.go:
            transaction.replace(R.id.content, new GoFragment());
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            transaction.commit();

            return true;

    }



    return false;
}
};

}
```

**UPDATE**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mapa);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.content, new MapFragment()).commit();

    BottomNavigationViewEx bottomNavigationViewEx = (BottomNavigationViewEx) findViewById(R.id.bottomViewBar);
    bottomNavigationViewEx.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

    BottomNavigationViewHelper.setupBottomNavigationView(bottomNavigationViewEx);
    bottomNavigationViewEx.setSelectedItemId(R.id.mapa);

    MenuItem item = bottomNavigationViewEx.getMenu().getItem(0);

    if (!item.isChecked()) item.setChecked(true);



}

private BottomNavigationViewEx.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();


        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.mapa:
                transaction.replace(R.id.content, new MapFragment());
                getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                transaction.commit();

                return true;

            case R.id.taxi:
                transaction.replace(R.id.content, new TaxiFragment());
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                transaction.commit();

                return true;

            case R.id.help:
                transaction.replace(R.id.content, new HelpFragment());
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                transaction.commit();

                return true;

            case R.id.go:
                transaction.replace(R.id.content, new GoFragment());
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                transaction.commit();

                return true;

        }



        return false;
    }
};

@Override
public void onBackPressed () {
    if (mCurrentItem > 0) {
        mCurrentItem--;
        showFragment (mCurrentItem);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}


private void showFragment(int currentItem) {

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();


    switch (currentItem) {
        case 0:
            transaction.replace(R.id.content, new MapFragment());
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            transaction.commit();

            break;

        case 1:
            transaction.replace(R.id.content, new TaxiFragment());
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            transaction.commit();
            break;

        case 2:
            transaction.replace(R.id.content, new HelpFragment());
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            transaction.commit();
            break;

        case 3:
            transaction.replace(R.id.content, new GoFragment());
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            transaction.commit();
            break;
    }
}



}
```

I have this now, but I don't know if is correct

Answer (score 0):

Keep a variable to denote which `Fragment` is your current. Inside `onBackPressed`, check what is the current `Fragment`, and decide where do you want to navigate to.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {            
    if (mCurrentItem > 0) {
        mCurrentItem--;
        showFragment(mCurrentItem);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Your `showFragment(mCurrentItem)` can show different page based on the value, or however you'd like it to.

```
private void showFragment(int currentItem) {
    switch (currentItem) {
        case 0:
            transaction.replace(R.id.content, new MapFragment());
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            transaction.commit();
            break;

        case 1:
            ...
    }
}
```

Then inside your `showFragment(currentItem)` method, add this code to select the item on `BottomNavigationView`:

```
MenuItem item = mBottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(mCurrentItem);

if (!item.isChecked()) item.setChecked(true);
```

Comment: Check my update  Please, I do not know how to apply it correctly, I am new.

Comment: I've never used onBackPressed

Answer (score 0):

Solve my problem by adding this line inside the class of my corresponding fragment in the onCreateView method, so when pressing back the item is selected.

```
BottomNavigationViewEx navigation = 
getActivity().findViewById(R.id.YourNavigationId);
    Menu drawer_menu = navigation.getMenu();
    MenuItem menuItem;
    menuItem = drawer_menu.findItem(R.id.YourItemId);
    if(!menuItem.isChecked())
    {
        menuItem.setChecked(true);
    }
```